# Where is the iteration running in this code?

Tags: c++, sockets, ros, ip-camera

I'm using NatNet SDK to receiving data from the cameras through tcp connection. In their example code below, it can print the stream data using DataHandler function while waiting for a while(c=_getchar()) loop. I have no idea why the code can both waiting for keyboard input and at the same time printing the camera's data in the DataHandler function in real time. I didn't see the code run in multi threads.

My second question is that how I can get the stream data in a for loop in the main function. If someone can tell me how to use that DataHandler to get data in the main function, that will be great.

```
//=============================================================================
// Copyright ?2014 NaturalPoint, Inc. All Rights Reserved.
// 
// This software is provided by the copyright holders and contributors "as is" and
// any express or implied warranties, including, but not limited to, the implied
// warranties of merchantability and fitness for a particular purpose are disclaimed.
// In no event shall NaturalPoint, Inc. or contributors be liable for any direct,
// indirect, incidental, special, exemplary, or consequential damages
// (including, but not limited to, procurement of substitute goods or services;
// loss of use, data, or profits; or business interruption) however caused
// and on any theory of liability, whether in contract, strict liability,
// or tort (including negligence or otherwise) arising in any way out of
// the use of this software, even if advised of the possibility of such damage.
//=============================================================================


/*

SampleClient.cpp

This program connects to a NatNet server, receives a data stream, and writes that data stream
to an ascii file.  The purpose is to illustrate using the NatNetClient class.

Usage [optional]:

    SampleClient [ServerIP] [LocalIP] [OutputFilename]

    [ServerIP]          IP address of the server (e.g. 192.168.0.107) ( defaults to local machine)
    [OutputFilename]    Name of points file (pts) to write out.  defaults to Client-output.pts

*/

#include <stdio.h>
#include <tchar.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <winsock2.h>

#include "NatNetTypes.h"
#include "NatNetClient.h"

#pragma warning( disable : 4996 )

void _WriteHeader(FILE* fp, sDataDescriptions* pBodyDefs);
void _WriteFrame(FILE* fp, sFrameOfMocapData* data);
void _WriteFooter(FILE* fp);
void __cdecl DataHandler(sFrameOfMocapData* data, void* pUserData);     // receives data from the server
void __cdecl MessageHandler(int msgType, char* msg);                    // receives NatNet error mesages
void resetClient();
int CreateClient(int iConnectionType);

unsigned int MyServersDataPort = 3130;
unsigned int MyServersCommandPort = 3131;
int iConnectionType = ConnectionType_Multicast;
//int iConnectionType = ConnectionType_Unicast;

NatNetClient* theClient;
FILE* fp;

char szMyIPAddress[128] = "";
char szServerIPAddress[128] = "";

int analogSamplesPerMocapFrame = 0;

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    int iResult;

    // parse command line args
    if(argc>1)
    {
        strcpy(szServerIPAddress, argv[1]); // specified on command line
        printf("Connecting to server at %s...\n", szServerIPAddress);
    }
    else
    {
        strcpy(szServerIPAddress, "");      // not specified - assume server is local machine
        printf("Connecting to server at LocalMachine\n");
    }
    if(argc>2)
    {
        strcpy(szMyIPAddress, argv[2]);     // specified on command line
        printf("Connecting from %s...\n", szMyIPAddress);
    }
    else
    {
        strcpy(szMyIPAddress, "");          // not specified - assume server is local machine
        printf("Connecting from LocalMachine...\n");
    }

    // Create NatNet Client
    iResult = CreateClient(iConnectionType);
    if(iResult != ErrorCode_OK)
    {
        printf("Error initializing client.  See log for details.  Exiting");
        return 1;
    }
    else
    {
        printf("Client initialized and ready.\n");
    }


    // send/receive test request
    printf("[SampleClient] Sending Test Request\n");
    void* response;
    int nBytes;
    iResult = theClient->SendMessageAndWait("TestRequest", &response, &nBytes);
    if (iResult == ErrorCode_OK)
    {
        printf("[SampleClient] Received: %s", (char*)response);
    }

    // Retrieve Data Descriptions from server
    printf("\n\n[SampleClient] Requesting Data Descriptions...");
    sDataDescriptions* pDataDefs = NULL;
    int nBodies = theClient->GetDataDescriptions(&pDataDefs);
    if(!pDataDefs)
    {
        printf("[SampleClient] Unable to retrieve Data Descriptions.");
    }
    else
    {
        printf("[SampleClient] Received %d Data Descriptions:\n", pDataDefs->nDataDescriptions );
        for(int i=0; i < pDataDefs->nDataDescriptions; i++)
        {
            printf("Data Description # %d (type=%d)\n", i, pDataDefs->arrDataDescriptions[i].type);
            if(pDataDefs->arrDataDescriptions[i].type == Descriptor_MarkerSet)
            {
                // MarkerSet
                sMarkerSetDescription* pMS = pDataDefs->arrDataDescriptions[i].Data.MarkerSetDescription;
                printf("MarkerSet Name : %s\n", pMS->szName);
                for(int i=0; i < pMS->nMarkers; i++)
                    printf("%s\n", pMS->szMarkerNames[i]);

            }
            else if(pDataDefs->arrDataDescriptions[i].type == Descriptor_RigidBody)
            {
                // RigidBody
                sRigidBodyDescription* pRB = pDataDefs->arrDataDescriptions[i].Data.RigidBodyDescription;
                printf("RigidBody Name : %s\n", pRB->szName);
                printf("RigidBody ID : %d\n", pRB->ID);
                printf("RigidBody Parent ID : %d\n", pRB->parentID);
                printf("Parent Offset : %3.2f,%3.2f,%3.2f\n", pRB->offsetx, pRB->offsety, pRB->offsetz);
            }
            else if(pDataDefs->arrDataDescriptions[i].type == Descriptor_Skeleton)
            {
                // Skeleton
                sSkeletonDescription* pSK = pDataDefs->arrDataDescriptions[i].Data.SkeletonDescription;
                printf("Skeleton Name : %s\n", pSK->szName);
                printf("Skeleton ID : %d\n", pSK->skeletonID);
                printf("RigidBody (Bone) Count : %d\n", pSK->nRigidBodies);
                for(int j=0; j < pSK->nRigidBodies; j++)
                {
                    sRigidBodyDescription* pRB = &pSK->RigidBodies[j];
                    printf("  RigidBody Name : %s\n", pRB->szName);
                    printf("  RigidBody ID : %d\n", pRB->ID);
                    printf("  RigidBody Parent ID : %d\n", pRB->parentID);
                    printf("  Parent Offset : %3.2f,%3.2f,%3.2f\n", pRB->offsetx, pRB->offsety, pRB->offsetz);
                }
            }
            else if(pDataDefs->arrDataDescriptions[i].type == Descriptor_ForcePlate)
            {
                // Force Plate
                sForcePlateDescription* pFP = pDataDefs->arrDataDescriptions[i].Data.ForcePlateDescription;
                printf("Force Plate ID : %d\n", pFP->ID);
                printf("Force Plate Serial : %s\n", pFP->strSerialNo);
                printf("Force Plate Width : %3.2f\n", pFP->fWidth);
                printf("Force Plate Length : %3.2f\n", pFP->fLength);
                printf("Force Plate Electrical Center Offset (%3.3f, %3.3f, %3.3f)\n", pFP->fOriginX,pFP->fOriginY, pFP->fOriginZ);
                for(int iCorner=0; iCorner<4; iCorner++)
                    printf("Force Plate Corner %d : (%3.4f, %3.4f, %3.4f)\n", iCorner, pFP->fCorners[iCorner][0],pFP->fCorners[iCorner][1],pFP->fCorners[iCorner][2]);
                printf("Force Plate Type : %d\n", pFP->iPlateType);
                printf("Force Plate Data Type : %d\n", pFP->iChannelDataType);
                printf("Force Plate Channel Count : %d\n", pFP->nChannels);
                for(int iChannel=0; iChannel<pFP->nChannels; iChannel++)
                    printf("\tChannel %d : %s\n", iChannel, pFP->szChannelNames[iChannel]);
            }
            else
            {
                printf("Unknown data type.");
                // Unknown
            }
        }      
    }


    // Create data file for writing received stream into
    char szFile[MAX_PATH];
    char szFolder[MAX_PATH];
    GetCurrentDirectory(MAX_PATH, szFolder);
    if(argc > 3)
        sprintf(szFile, "%s\\%s", szFolder, argv[3]);
    else
        sprintf(szFile, "%s\\Client-output.pts",szFolder);
    fp = fopen(szFile, "w");
    if(!fp)
    {
        printf("error opening output file %s.  Exiting.", szFile);
        exit(1);
    }
    if(pDataDefs)
        _WriteHeader(fp, pDataDefs);

    // Ready to receive marker stream!
    printf("\nClient is connected to server and listening for data...\n");
    int c;
    bool bExit = false;
    while(c =_getch())
    {
        switch(c)
        {
            case 'q':
                bExit = true;       
                break;  
            case 'r':
                resetClient();
                break;  
            case 'p':
                sServerDescription ServerDescription;
                memset(&ServerDescription, 0, sizeof(ServerDescription));
                theClient->GetServerDescription(&ServerDescription);
                if(!ServerDescription.HostPresent)
                {
                    printf("Unable to connect to server. Host not present. Exiting.");
                    return 1;
                }
                break;  
            case 'f':
                {
                    sFrameOfMocapData* pData = theClient->GetLastFrameOfData();
                    printf("Most Recent Frame: %d", pData->iFrame);
                }
                break;  
            case 'm':                           // change to multicast
                iConnectionType = ConnectionType_Multicast;
                iResult = CreateClient(iConnectionType);
                if(iResult == ErrorCode_OK)
                    printf("Client connection type changed to Multicast.\n\n");
                else
                    printf("Error changing client connection type to Multicast.\n\n");
                break;
            case 'u':                           // change to unicast
                iConnectionType = ConnectionType_Unicast;
                iResult = CreateClient(iConnectionType);
                if(iResult == ErrorCode_OK)
                    printf("Client connection type changed to Unicast.\n\n");
                else
                    printf("Error changing client connection type to Unicast.\n\n");
                break;
            case 'c' :                          // connect
                iResult = CreateClient(iConnectionType);
                break;
            case 'd' :                          // disconnect
                // note: applies to unicast connections only - indicates to Motive to stop sending packets to that client endpoint
                iResult = theClient->SendMessageAndWait("Disconnect", &response, &nBytes);
                if (iResult == ErrorCode_OK)
                    printf("[SampleClient] Disconnected");
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
        if(bExit)
            break;
    }

    // Done - clean up.
    theClient->Uninitialize();
    _WriteFooter(fp);
    fclose(fp);

    return ErrorCode_OK;
}

// Establish a NatNet Client connection
int CreateClient(int iConnectionType)
{
    // release previous server
    if(theClient)
    {
        theClient->Uninitialize();
        delete theClient;
    }

    // create NatNet client
    theClient = new NatNetClient(iConnectionType);



    // set the callback handlers
    theClient->SetVerbosityLevel(Verbosity_Warning);
    theClient->SetMessageCallback(MessageHandler);
    theClient->SetDataCallback( DataHandler, theClient );   // this function will receive data from the server
    // [optional] use old multicast group
    //theClient->SetMulticastAddress("224.0.0.1");

    // print version info
    unsigned char ver[4];
    theClient->NatNetVersion(ver);
    printf("NatNet Sample Client (NatNet ver. %d.%d.%d.%d)\n", ver[0], ver[1], ver[2], ver[3]);

    // Init Client and connect to NatNet server
    // to use NatNet default port assignments
    int retCode = theClient->Initialize(szMyIPAddress, szServerIPAddress);
    // to use a different port for commands and/or data:
    //int retCode = theClient->Initialize(szMyIPAddress, szServerIPAddress, MyServersCommandPort, MyServersDataPort);
    if (retCode != ErrorCode_OK)
    {
        printf("Unable to connect to server.  Error code: %d. Exiting", retCode);
        return ErrorCode_Internal;
    }
    else
    {
        // get # of analog samples per mocap frame of data
        void* pResult;
        int ret = 0;
        int nBytes = 0;
        ret = theClient->SendMessageAndWait("AnalogSamplesPerMocapFrame", &pResult, &nBytes);
        if (ret == ErrorCode_OK)
        {
            analogSamplesPerMocapFrame = *((int*)pResult);
            printf("Analog Samples Per Mocap Frame : %d", analogSamplesPerMocapFrame);
        }

        // print server info
        sServerDescription ServerDescription;
        memset(&ServerDescription, 0, sizeof(ServerDescription));
        theClient->GetServerDescription(&ServerDescription);
        if(!ServerDescription.HostPresent)
        {
            printf("Unable to connect to server. Host not present. Exiting.");
            return 1;
        }
        printf("[SampleClient] Server application info:\n");
        printf("Application: %s (ver. %d.%d.%d.%d)\n", ServerDescription.szHostApp, ServerDescription.HostAppVersion[0],
            ServerDescription.HostAppVersion[1],ServerDescription.HostAppVersion[2],ServerDescription.HostAppVersion[3]);
        printf("NatNet Version: %d.%d.%d.%d\n", ServerDescription.NatNetVersion[0], ServerDescription.NatNetVersion[1],
            ServerDescription.NatNetVersion[2], ServerDescription.NatNetVersion[3]);
        printf("Client IP:%s\n", szMyIPAddress);
        printf("Server IP:%s\n", szServerIPAddress);
        printf("Server Name:%s\n\n", ServerDescription.szHostComputerName);
    }

    return ErrorCode_OK;

}

// DataHandler receives data from the server
void __cdecl DataHandler(sFrameOfMocapData* data, void* pUserData)
{
    NatNetClient* pClient = (NatNetClient*) pUserData;

    if(fp)
        _WriteFrame(fp,data);

    int i=0;

    printf("FrameID : %d\n", data->iFrame);
    printf("Timestamp :  %3.2lf\n", data->fTimestamp);
    printf("Latency :  %3.2lf\n", data->fLatency);

    // FrameOfMocapData params
    bool bIsRecording = ((data->params & 0x01)!=0);
    bool bTrackedModelsChanged = ((data->params & 0x02)!=0);
    if(bIsRecording)
        printf("RECORDING\n");
    if(bTrackedModelsChanged)
        printf("Models Changed.\n");


    // timecode - for systems with an eSync and SMPTE timecode generator - decode to values
    int hour, minute, second, frame, subframe;
    bool bValid = pClient->DecodeTimecode(data->Timecode, data->TimecodeSubframe, &hour, &minute, &second, &frame, &subframe);
    // decode to friendly string
    char szTimecode[128] = "";
    pClient->TimecodeStringify(data->Timecode, data->TimecodeSubframe, szTimecode, 128);
    printf("Timecode : %s\n", szTimecode);

    // Other Markers
    printf("Other Markers [Count=%d]\n", data->nOtherMarkers);
    for(i=0; i < data->nOtherMarkers; i++)
    {
        printf("Other Marker %d : %3.2f\t%3.2f\t%3.2f\n",
            i,
            data->OtherMarkers[i][0],
            data->OtherMarkers[i][1],
            data->OtherMarkers[i][2]);
    }

    // Rigid Bodies
    printf("Rigid Bodies [Count=%d]\n", data->nRigidBodies);
    for(i=0; i < data->nRigidBodies; i++)
    {
        // params
        // 0x01 : bool, rigid body was successfully tracked in this frame
        bool bTrackingValid = data->RigidBodies[i].params & 0x01;

        printf("Rigid Body [ID=%d  Error=%3.2f  Valid=%d]\n", data->RigidBodies[i].ID, data->RigidBodies[i].MeanError, bTrackingValid);
        printf("\tx\ty\tz\tqx\tqy\tqz\tqw\n");
        printf("\t%3.2f\t%3.2f\t%3.2f\t%3.2f\t%3.2f\t%3.2f\t%3.2f\n",
            data->RigidBodies[i].x,
            data->RigidBodies[i].y,
            data->RigidBodies[i].z,
            data->RigidBodies[i].qx,
            data->RigidBodies[i].qy,
            data->RigidBodies[i].qz,
            data->RigidBodies[i].qw);

        printf("\tRigid body markers [Count=%d]\n", data->RigidBodies[i].nMarkers);
        for(int iMarker=0; iMarker < data->RigidBodies[i].nMarkers; iMarker++)
        {
            printf("\t\t");
            if(data->RigidBodies[i].MarkerIDs)
                printf("MarkerID:%d", data->RigidBodies[i].MarkerIDs[iMarker]);
            if(data->RigidBodies[i].MarkerSizes)
                printf("\tMarkerSize:%3.2f", data->RigidBodies[i].MarkerSizes[iMarker]);
            if(data->RigidBodies[i].Markers)
                printf("\tMarkerPos:%3.2f,%3.2f,%3.2f\n" ,
                    data->RigidBodies[i].Markers[iMarker][0],
                    data->RigidBodies[i].Markers[iMarker][1],
                    data->RigidBodies[i].Markers[iMarker][2]);
        }
    }

    // skeletons
    printf("Skeletons [Count=%d]\n", data->nSkeletons);
    for(i=0; i < data->nSkeletons; i++)
    {
        sSkeletonData skData = data->Skeletons[i];
        printf("Skeleton [ID=%d  Bone count=%d]\n", skData.skeletonID, skData.nRigidBodies);
        for(int j=0; j< skData.nRigidBodies; j++)
        {
            sRigidBodyData rbData = skData.RigidBodyData[j];
            printf("Bone %d\t%3.2f\t%3.2f\t%3.2f\t%3.2f\t%3.2f\t%3.2f\t%3.2f\n",
                rbData.ID, rbData.x, rbData.y, rbData.z, rbData.qx, rbData.qy, rbData.qz, rbData.qw );

            printf("\tRigid body markers [Count=%d]\n", rbData.nMarkers);
            for(int iMarker=0; iMarker < rbData.nMarkers; iMarker++)
            {
                printf("\t\t");
                if(rbData.MarkerIDs)
                    printf("MarkerID:%d", rbData.MarkerIDs[iMarker]);
                if(rbData.MarkerSizes)
                    printf("\tMarkerSize:%3.2f", rbData.MarkerSizes[iMarker]);
                if(rbData.Markers)
                    printf("\tMarkerPos:%3.2f,%3.2f,%3.2f\n" ,
                    data->RigidBodies[i].Markers[iMarker][0],
                    data->RigidBodies[i].Markers[iMarker][1],
                    data->RigidBodies[i].Markers[iMarker][2]);
            }
        }
    }

    // labeled markers
    bool bOccluded;     // marker was not visible (occluded) in this frame
    bool bPCSolved;     // reported position provided by point cloud solve
    bool bModelSolved;  // reported position provided by model solve
    printf("Labeled Markers [Count=%d]\n", data->nLabeledMarkers);
    for(i=0; i < data->nLabeledMarkers; i++)
    {
        bOccluded = ((data->LabeledMarkers[i].params & 0x01)!=0);
        bPCSolved = ((data->LabeledMarkers[i].params & 0x02)!=0);
        bModelSolved = ((data->LabeledMarkers[i].params & 0x04)!=0);
        sMarker marker = data->LabeledMarkers[i];
        int modelID, markerID;
        theClient->DecodeID(marker.ID, &modelID, &markerID);
        printf("Labeled Marker [ModelID=%d, MarkerID=%d, Occluded=%d, PCSolved=%d, ModelSolved=%d] [size=%3.2f] [pos=%3.2f,%3.2f,%3.2f]\n",
            modelID, markerID, bOccluded, bPCSolved, bModelSolved,  marker.size, marker.x, marker.y, marker.z);
    }

    // force plates
    if(data->nForcePlates==0)
    {
        printf("No Plates\n");
    }
    printf("Force Plate [Count=%d]\n", data->nForcePlates);
    for(int iPlate=0; iPlate < data->nForcePlates; iPlate++)
    {
        printf("Force Plate %d\n", data->ForcePlates[iPlate].ID);
        for(int iChannel=0; iChannel < data->ForcePlates[iPlate].nChannels; iChannel++)
        {
            printf("\tChannel %d:\t", iChannel);
            if(data->ForcePlates[iPlate].ChannelData[iChannel].nFrames == 0)
            {
                printf("\tEmpty Frame\n");
            }
            else if(data->ForcePlates[iPlate].ChannelData[iChannel].nFrames != analogSamplesPerMocapFrame)
            {
                printf("\tPartial Frame [Expected:%d   Actual:%d]\n", analogSamplesPerMocapFrame, data->ForcePlates[iPlate].ChannelData[iChannel].nFrames);
            }
            for(int iSample=0; iSample < data->ForcePlates[iPlate].ChannelData[iChannel].nFrames; iSample++)
                printf("%3.2f\t", data->ForcePlates[iPlate].ChannelData[iChannel].Values[iSample]);
            printf("\n");
        }
    }

}

// MessageHandler receives NatNet error/debug messages
void __cdecl MessageHandler(int msgType, char* msg)
{
    printf("\n%s\n", msg);
}

/* File writing routines */
void _WriteHeader(FILE* fp, sDataDescriptions* pBodyDefs)
{
    int i=0;

    if(!pBodyDefs->arrDataDescriptions[0].type == Descriptor_MarkerSet)
        return;

    sMarkerSetDescription* pMS = pBodyDefs->arrDataDescriptions[0].Data.MarkerSetDescription;

    fprintf(fp, "<MarkerSet>\n\n");
    fprintf(fp, "<Name>\n%s\n</Name>\n\n", pMS->szName);

    fprintf(fp, "<Markers>\n");
    for(i=0; i < pMS->nMarkers; i++)
    {
        fprintf(fp, "%s\n", pMS->szMarkerNames[i]);
    }
    fprintf(fp, "</Markers>\n\n");

    fprintf(fp, "<Data>\n");
    fprintf(fp, "Frame#\t");
    for(i=0; i < pMS->nMarkers; i++)
    {
        fprintf(fp, "M%dX\tM%dY\tM%dZ\t", i, i, i);
    }
    fprintf(fp,"\n");

}

void _WriteFrame(FILE* fp, sFrameOfMocapData* data)
{
    fprintf(fp, "%d", data->iFrame);
    for(int i =0; i < data->MocapData->nMarkers; i++)
    {
        fprintf(fp, "\t%.5f\t%.5f\t%.5f", data->MocapData->Markers[i][0], data->MocapData->Markers[i][1], data->MocapData->Markers[i][2]);
    }
    fprintf(fp, "\n");
}

void _WriteFooter(FILE* fp)
{
    fprintf(fp, "</Data>\n\n");
    fprintf(fp, "</MarkerSet>\n");
}

void resetClient()
{
    int iSuccess;

    printf("\n\nre-setting Client\n\n.");

    iSuccess = theClient->Uninitialize();
    if(iSuccess != 0)
        printf("error un-initting Client\n");

    iSuccess = theClient->Initialize(szMyIPAddress, szServerIPAddress);
    if(iSuccess != 0)
        printf("error re-initting Client\n");


}
```

Comment: By the way, I have to open Motive software for sending data first. The code above is to receive the data through tcp connection. http://www.optitrack.com/products/motive/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Very likely NatNetClient() or client->Initialize() is creating a new thread in the background. Since I do not have access to their code, I can't validate reliably.

You can either create a synchronous look in the main and always send and receive messages via NatNetClient::SendMessageAndWait 
or
To receive data asyncronously, you need to figure out a way to poll on stdin (for getch) and also wait on a lock simultaneously. I am not sure how to do this on Microsoft console. If you figure that out, then when the handler gets control, de-queue the message into a link-list and wakup a mutex to notify the main.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I guess your are right for the first questions. I tried to define a global variable so that I use ::myglobalvariablex=xpos in DataHandler. When I tried to print out the global variable in the while(c_getchar()) loop, it prints the updated data when I press the keyboard. But if I change it from while(c=_getchar()) to while(1), it never print out the correct data. The results are always 0.0000.

Answer (score 0):

The NatNet sample spins off a different thread for handling the data using the DataHandler function. The following line is where this happens:

```
theClient->SetDataCallback( DataHandler, theClient );
```

I would recommend doing the processing strictly in the DataHandler function. However, if talking between threads in necessary, then it's worth looking into the C++ 11 libraries

```
#include <threads>
#include <mutex>
```

Specifically [mutex](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/mutex/) is used to lock and unlock threads in C++. You could create a global variable and write to it using the DataHandler function, then use that global variable in your main function. The problem is that you may read and write the data at the same time, because main and DataHandler are on different threads. So you can use the mutex library to lock a thread while reading or writing that global variable (meaning only that thread is allowed to run while doing that process).

Note: The NatNet sample actually uses a UDP transmission not TCP.